# How does one handle a word-ending contraction followed by a comma and a closing single quote?

Tags: writing-style, punctuation, quotes

Here's the line; it looks horrible:

“Who’s your ‘frien’,’ Jake?”

It seems grammatically correct. Does anyone have a better way to do it (other than rewriting/reorganizing the sentence)?

Notes:
 - The speaker has been established as one who speaks similarly to Jim from Huckleberry Finn, using terms like "frien'" for "friend", "tol'" for "told", "drivin'" for "driving," etc. when he is being directly quoted.
 - The "friend" mentioned is not really a friend of Jake; the quotes indicate sarcasm.
 - I considered and rejected the use of italics: “Who’s your *frien'*, Jake?” Should I reconsider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Italics plus the trailing apostrophe ....

"Who's your *frien'*, Jake?"

Looks okay this way.

Or you can instead try to add an extra word or so, to indicate the sarcasm:

"Who's your ... (snorts) ... frien', Jake?"

Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what you are trying to emphasize. If it's more important to get the sense of Jake's dialect in there, then I'd use italics. If it's more important to emphasize the sarcasm, I'd use "friend" without the dropped last letter. If they are both important, I think I'd use italics and then try to add the sarcasm to the tag:

"Who's your *frien*, Jake?" I asked, my voice dripping with sarcasm.

Kristen